# add two textbox values in jquery after getting by JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have three text boxes having ids: textbox1, textbox2, textbox3. I am retrieving values for first two textboxes from combo1.jsp by JSON and i want to add these two values and to display it on 3rd textboxes. Values of 1st textbox and 2nd textbox are coming from db, only i want to add these two values and to display in 3rd textbox.

```
  $("#combo1").change(function() {
$.getJSON('combo1.jsp', { combo1Val : $(this).val() }, function(data) {
 $("#textbox1").val(data.a);// suppose a's value came as 10 from db
$("#textbox2").val(data.b);// b's value came as 20 from db
 $("#textbox3").val(data.c);// here i want to show the sum(a+b) that is 30
});
});
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#combo1").change(function() {
    $.getJSON(
        'combo1.jsp', 
        { combo1Val : $(this).val() }, 
        function(data) {
            var a = data.a; // suppose a's value came as 10 from db
            var b = data.b; // b's value came as 20 from db
            var total = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);

            $("#textbox1").val(a)
            $("#textbox2").val(b)
            $("#textbox3").val(total); // here i want to show the sum(a+b) that is 30
        }
    );
});
```

You can cut this down if required, I've just made it as clear as possible how it's working.

**UPDATE**

To update the sum after changing either value, try this:

```
$("#textbox1, #textbox2").keyup(function() {
    var a = $("#textbox1").val();
    var b = $("#textbox2").val();
    var total = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    $("#textbox3").val(total);
});
```

Comment: thanks Rory, just one more question, if i want to edit value b then after pressing TAB key, how sum can be changed accordingly? suppose a's value came as 10, b's value came as 20, then sum shows as 30. Now if i will edit value of b to 25, then immediately value of total will show 35. How can i do it?

Comment: @Rory..i faced a problem here. if a's value is 633 and b's value is 010, then total is giving 641? Please suggest any idea how to correct it

Comment: @Harry Try opening a new question for that one.

Answer (score 1):

A bit odd but this could work:

```
$("#textbox3").val(+data.a + +data.b);
```

Same as:

```
$("#textbox3").val(parseInt(data.a,10) + parseInt(data.b,10));
```

**UPDATE: added recompute function when values are changed from UI**

```
function recompute(){
     var a = parseInt($("#textbox1").val(),10);
     var b = parseInt($("#textbox2").val(),10);
     var sum = a + b;
     $('#textbox3').val( sum );
}

$('#textbox1,#textbox2').change(recompute);
```

Comment: @jerjer..please have a look at my comments on Rory's answer, if you can provide an idea

Comment: 1 thing to add, parseInt(value) without specifying the base, will yield incorrect results if the value starts with 0 like 010, javascript treat them as non decimal values

Comment: parseInt(value, 10); //10- is the base, that should correct it

Comment: ya but how can i add value as 10 like parseInt(value, 10); , it is coming from db, so it may be any value. value of a may be 10, 20, 30 etc..

Comment: the base is just an additional parameter of the parseInt function to tell javascript that you want a decimal result not an octal value

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#combo1").change(function() {
$.getJSON('combo1.jsp', { combo1Val : $(this).val() }, function(data) {
 $("#textbox1").val(data.a);// suppose a's value came as 10 from db
$("#textbox2").val(data.b);// b's value came as 20 from db
 $("#textbox3").val(parseInt(data.a)+parseInt(data.b));// here i want to show the sum(a+b) that is 30
});
});
```

Comment: @Akhil..thanks for your response well above solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#combo1").change(function() {
  $.getJSON('combo1.jsp', { combo1Val : $(this).val() }, function(data) {
    $("#textbox1").val(data.a);// suppose a's value came as 10 from db
    $("#textbox2").val(data.b);// b's value came as 20 from db

    var c = $("#textbox2").val() + $("#textbox1").val();
   $("#textbox3").val(c);
 });
});
```

Comment: @kynsai..thanks for your response well above solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON(msg.d,function(i,data){

var a=parseInt(data.a);//after yo get data injsonformat parse it to int 
var b=parseInt(data.b);
var total=a+b;//this is just a simple arithematic addition
$('#textbox3').val(total);//assigning the value to the textbox

}
```